# laravel query builder expression about one to many table from the sql expression

Tags: laravel, select, count, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

```
a16s            
id  pic     
1   1.jpg       
2   2.jpg       
3   3.jpg       
4   4.jpg       

a16s_like           
id  p_id u_id   approve
1   1       2   0
2   1       1   1
3   1       5   1
4   1       6   1
5   1       7   0
6   2       2   0
7   2       3   0
8   2       1   1
9   4       4   0
10  4       3   1
11  4       2   1


SELECT 
    A.id, 
    A.PIC, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN  B.approve IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Ashowcunt,
    SUM(CASE WHEN  B.approve=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Nshow,
    SUM(CASE WHEN  B.approve=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yshow,
    B.approve,
    SUM(CASE WHEN  B.approve=1 AND B.u_id=3 THEN 1 when B.approve=0 AND B.u_id=3 then 0 ELSE null END) AS U_id3show
FROM  a16s AS A
LEFT JOIN a16s_like  AS B ON A.ID = B.p_id 
GROUP BY A.id,A.pic
```

to get the list and work well on mysql 5.7

when the u_id=2 to excute the select , I get

```
id pic    Ashowocunt  approve_0_count  approve_1_count     u_id2_approve   
1  1.jpg   5          2                3                   0
2  2.jpg   3          2                1                   0
3  3.jpg   0          0                0                   null
4. 4.jpg   3          0                3                   0
```

u_id=3

```
id pic    Ashowocunt  approve_0_count  approve_1_count     u_id3_approve   
1  1.jpg   0          0                0                   null
2  2.jpg   0          1                0                   0
3  3.jpg   0          0                0                   null
4. 4.jpg   1          0                1                   1
```

when I change the sql to laravel

```
$search_alls=
DB::select('A.id','A.route','B.approve')
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Ashowcount'))
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Nshow'))
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yshow'))
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve = 1 AND b.u_id = 2 then 1 
                                  when B.approve = 0 AND b.u_id = 2 then 0 ELSE null END) as U_idshow'))
    ->from('a16s as A')
    ->join('a16s_like as B', function($join) {
        $join->on('A.ID', '=', 'B.p_id');
        })
    ->groupBy('A.id')
    ->orderby('A.id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(12);


    return View('comefo.results')
            ->with('search_alls', $search_alls)
            ->with('table',$table);
```

I got the error

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in D:\AppServ\www\product\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 665

Comment: First of all, you passing wrong parameters to function groupBy.

Comment: What's the result of `dd(DB::select(...->groupBy(...)->toSql());`?

Comment: @VasylSovyak thanks I  modify groupby  but still the same error

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir the error message is the same .Type error: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in D:\AppServ\www\product\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly create a query:

```
DB::query()->select(...
```

Comment: But when I search the function of query(). I don't know the correct moment to use  'query()->select  ...from('tablename')'  or ' DB::table('tablename') ->select...' Are they different on different situation?

Comment: There's no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You place the table name in the wrong place. Use `table` method.

```
echo DB::table('a16s as A')
     ->select('A.id','A.route','B.approve')
     ...
     ->orderby('A.id', 'DESC')->toSql();
```

reveals normal sql like

> select `A`.`id`, `A`.`route`, `B`.`approve`, SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve
>   IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Ashowcount, SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve = 0
>   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Nshow, SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
>   END) as Yshow, SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve = 1 AND b.u_id = 2 then 1 when
>   B.approve = 0 AND b.u_id = 2 then 0 ELSE null END) as U_idshow from
>   `a16s` as `A` inner join `a16s_like` as `B` on `A`.`ID` = `B`.`p_id`
>   group by `A`.`id` order by `A`.`id` desc

Comment: Tested using `php artisan tinker`.

Comment: I got what I need! Thanks for yourhelp~